# Why is my fragment not attached to my activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

So I'm trying to call content resolver inside my fragment that is a part of a fragment for bottom navigation in my MainActivity. I'm trying to fetch data from database using contentResolver and show data in recyclerview inside my fragment. This is the code for my mainactivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    replaceFragment(homeFragment)
    binding.bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when(it.itemId){
            R.id.ic_home -> replaceFragment(homeFragment)
            R.id.ic_profile -> replaceFragment(profileFragment)
            R.id.ic_favorite -> replaceFragment(favoriteFragment)
            R.id.ic_settings -> replaceFragment(settingsFragment)
        }
        true
    }
}

private fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    if (fragment!=null){
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Here is the code inside my fragment:

```
class FavoriteFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var binding: FragmentFavoriteBinding
private lateinit var rvFavorites: RecyclerView
val listUserAdapter = FavoriteAdapter()
private var contentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val handlerThread = HandlerThread("DataObserver")
    handlerThread.start()
    val handler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)

    val myObserver = object: ContentObserver(handler){
        override fun onChange(selfChange: Boolean) {
            showRecyclerList()
        }
    }
    contentResolver?.registerContentObserver(DatabaseContract.UserColumns.CONTENT_URI,true,myObserver)

}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = FragmentFavoriteBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
    rvFavorites = binding.rvFavorites

    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val githubToolbarButton = binding.toolbar.gitHubLogo
    githubToolbarButton.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.github.com"))
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    showRecyclerList()

}

private fun getItemsList(): ArrayList<FavoriteUser>{
    val cursor = contentResolver?.query(DatabaseContract.UserColumns.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null)
    val users = MappingHelper.mapCursorToArrayList(cursor)
    return users
}

private fun showRecyclerList() {
    rvFavorites.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    listUserAdapter.setData(getItemsList())
    rvFavorites.adapter = listUserAdapter
}
```

}

Here is also the log:

```
2021-04-17 03:15:43.635 27132-27132/com.dicoding.githubclone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dicoding.githubclone, PID: 27132
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.dicoding.githubclone/com.dicoding.githubclone.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FavoriteFragment{a05adfe} (71b7cd2d-192f-4663-9ac9-e6db08d6d441)} not attached to an activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3641)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3883)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8107)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:626)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FavoriteFragment{a05adfe} (71b7cd2d-192f-4663-9ac9-e6db08d6d441)} not attached to an activity.
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.requireActivity(Fragment.java:833)
    at com.dicoding.githubclone.fragment.FavoriteFragment.<init>(FavoriteFragment.kt:27)
    at com.dicoding.githubclone.activity.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:30)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1253)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3629)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is coming from this lines.

private var contentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver

Try to init this property in onViewCreated method in this way

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
contentResolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
contentResolver?.registerContentObserver(DatabaseContract.UserColumns.CONTENT_URI,true,myObserver)
}